# return NA in rollapply?

Tags: r

```
x <- 1:10
x[6] <- NA
x
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5 NA  7  8  9 10
rollapply(x, 3, mean)
#[1] 2  3  4 NA NA NA  8  9
```

I want `rollapply` to return NA in case there are more than 3 NAs in the moving window.
Is it possible?

Comment: Something like this? `rollapply(x, 3, function(x) ifelse(sum(is.na(x))>3, NA, mean(x, na.rm=T)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this directly by changing your `function` argument in `rollapply`. Something like:

```
#Same input as d.b
x = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 9L, 10L)

rollapply(x, 3, function(x) ifelse(sum(is.na(x))>=3, NA, mean(x, na.rm=T)))
#[1] 2.0 3.0 3.5 4.0  NA 8.0 8.5 9.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use `rollapply` again to find out indices with three or more `NA` and replace values for those indices with `NA`

```
x = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 9L, 10L)

library(zoo)
replace(x = rollapply(x, 3, mean, na.rm = TRUE),
       list = which(rollapply(data = is.na(x), 3, sum) >= 3),
       values = NA)
#[1] 2.0 3.0 3.5 4.0  NA 8.0 8.5 9.0
```